# What is the correct way to host .well-known/openid-configuration?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, blazor, openid-connect, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server Project based on ASP.NET Core 5. I want to host my own openid-configuration discovery file. Since this file is served while running the OIDC workflow I want to verify what is the correct way to host this file. So far I have tried the following and only option 2 works.

1. **using wwwroot/.well-known**

This involves hosting the openid-configuration file statically in the wwwroot folder of my blazor server project.

[image]

After this if I run he project and try to access the file using localhost:44382/.well-known/openid-configuration, **the file is not served.**

2. **Using Controllers**

For this I just added a simple controller to my blazor project and specified .well-known/openid-configuration as a route for my anonymous controller HTTPGET action.

```
public class OidcConfigurationController : Controller
{      

    [HttpGet(".well-known/openid-configuration")]
    public JsonResult OpenIdConfiguration()
    {
        return Json(new Storage.Storables.Security.OIDC.Configuration());
    }   
}
```

Now if I run the project with Option 2 and try to reach the localhost:44382/.well-known/openid-configuration the **configuration JSON is served correctly.**

[image]

Is option 2 the correct way to serve the OpenId-Configuration using ASP.NET Core and Blazor server project ? Will it cause any issues if I publish the server (for e.g. to Azure)

Comment: Have you tried to test it with IIS Express?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your first method is not working is that you don't serve a static file in a way the static file extensions assume you do. You missing a file ending, otherwise, the request isn't recognized as a file.

That said, you can write your own middleware. Give the file a proper ending like .json. If the resources `/.well-known/openid-configuration/` is requested, you change the requested path to `/.well-known/openid-configuration.json` and let the static file extension handle the rest.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
            ...
          

            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Path == "/.well-known/openid-configuration")
                {
                    context.Request.Path = "/.well-known/openid-configuration.json";
                }
           
                await next();
            });

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            ...
}
```

For more information about writing a middleware have a look at the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write

However, you ran into the problem - I guess - because mostly this document is generated on the fly based on the configuration of your open id connect server like IdentityServer. So, maybe there is away around the static file?

Comment: Thanks, yes making changes as suggested does work now. So what should be the preferred approach wwwroot or controllers ?

Comment: Two questions: Does the files' content change during runtime, and if not, how easy is it to generate during startup/deploy/build? If it rarely changes, I'd suggest using the wwwroot method but with a real middleware like explained in the article. So, you would call something like ```app.ProvideStaticOIDCConfiguration()```. If it is dynamic, to me, the controller approach seems to be more reasonable. 

Besides, if the answer solved your problem, could you mark it as solved?

Comment: Ok, I would go with controllers as that enables me to change the content during runtime.